# Вывод данных в html

Tags: php, html, парсер

Допустим у нас имеется html страницы (вывод тела):

```
<div>Добро пожаловать $name.</div>
```

Пока опустим правила вывода текста, с использованием htmlspecialchars и прочих правил... Ибо вопрос в механике.

Наполнять html страницу таким содержимым не есть хорошо, да и не совсем удобно. По сути - нужно избавляться от php кода в html, как я понял.

Если я так же правильно понял - подобными делами занимается парсер. Можно и через DOM искать, либо через регулярные выражения...

Я ищу немного другой подход, возможно он и есть. К примеру:

```
<!-- START: text -->
<div>Добро пожаловать {name}.</div>
<!-- END: text -->
```

В свою очередь `{name}` является тем самым именем пользователя, которое необходимо вывести на экран, используя методы вывода в php.

Либо, если вдруг у нас есть таблица, то будем иметь подобный вид:

```
<!-- START: text -->
<div>
    <span>Вывод {text.name}</span>
    <!-- START: table-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Фамилия</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- START: row-->
        <tr>
            <td>{table.firstname}</td>
            <td>{table.lastname}</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- END: row-->
    </table>
    <!-- END: table-->
</div>
<!-- END: text -->
```

В данной конструкции мы уже вывод храним в массиве и имеем иерархическую структуру вывода - выводим строки таблицы в цикле. В случае, если нам нужно вывести 2 одинаковые таблицы на страницы - будет отсутствие конфликта в подобном случае.

В связи с вышеперечисленным - вопрос: есть ли подобные парсеры, производящие вывод данных html в подобном виде? Написать можно, алгоритм есть, но смысл придумывать велосипед?:)

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону шаблонизатора с webdev
Там даже синтаксис похож на написанное Вами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То о чем вы пишите называется шаблонизатором. Он бывает и в js и в php и в других языках.

Есть подход в разработке приложений называется [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). В нем принято разделять приложения. На модель(данные), контроллер(логика) и представление и вот за представления и отвечают разного вида шаблонизаторы. Они призваны убрать влияние php кода в шаблонах сайта.

Вот шаблонизаторы например для php

- https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom
- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Вот на js

- http://handlebarsjs.com/
- http://mustache.github.io/
- http://leonidas.github.io/transparency/

[Статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/75901/) на хабре про шаблонизаторы в php.